# Iterate through dict keys in Django Templates

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

i have a dict that im passing to my template from my view, but i cant get the dict to show data correctly, if at all. the dict is as follows:

```
context_dct = {

    'product0': {
        'totalentries': '6', 
        'type': 'hammers', 
        'brandname': 'DEWALT', 
        'price': '$25.84'}, 

    'product1': {
        'totalentries': '5', 
        'type': 'hammers', 
        'brandname': 'DEWALT', 
        'price': '$25.84'}, 

    'product2': {
        'totalentries': '8', 
        'type': 'hammers', 
        'brandname': 'DEWALT', 
        'price': '$25.84'}
}
```

using django 2.2 and python3, i passed the dict to my template via render(), and attempted to access it like so:

```
<h1>Results:</h1>
{% for key, value in context_dct.items %}
    <h1>{{ key }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ value }}</h1>
    </br>
{% endfor %}
```

but the only thing that shows up is "Results" in the h1 tags. i've also tried several other ways of accessing the dictionary, similar to normal python dictionary access, to no avail. i can get it to work correctly when i dont use a nested dictionary, but using it this way, i havent been able to get it to work. is there something im missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your dictionary into another dictionary, to give it a name, like:

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', { 'context_dct': context_dct })
```

Otherwise, you defined variables like `product0`, `product1`, etc.

Comment: excellent, it works. can i ask, why does this work though? im not understanding whats going on here fully. i hope thats not too nooby of a question.

Comment: @data_the_goonie: the dictionary maps the variable names in the template to the content. If you pass your `context_dct` directly it thus maps `product0` to that dictionary, etc. But you want to access the dictionary as a variable itself, so we can fix that by constructing a dictionary that maps `'context_dct'` (the name) to the content.

Comment: how then would i access each individual key value once i get it into the template? i can get them to print out iteratively now, but i want to be able to manipulate them each individually.

Comment: @data_the_goonie: you can pass them in the dictionary as well, by writing it as `{ 'context_dct': context_dct, **context_dct }`.